# BufferedImageOp Kernel Convolution not doing anything

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I am attempting to perform a basic kernel convolution pass on an image using the `BufferedImageOp` package in `java.awt.image`. This is the code I have:

```java
BufferedImage img = null;
File f = null;

//read image
try {
  f = new File("keys.JPG");
  img = ImageIO.read(f);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}

float[] gaussian = {
  1/16f, 1/8f, 1/16f,
  1/8f, 1/4f, 1/8f,
  1/16f, 1/8f, 1/16f,
};

BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(new Kernel(3, 3, gaussian));
BufferedImage dest = op.filter(img, null);
File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(dest, "jpg", outputfile);
```

My code attempts to load the image `keys.JPG` and then convolve this image with the Gaussian blur kernel and save the image to the file `image.jpg`. When I run the code, it processes for a bit then terminates and saves the image successfully but when I compare the original and the new images, they are identical.

Looking online at some code examples, my code should work. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I just compiled and ran your code, and it works for me. Maybe the effect is just not as visible as you expected? Is your input image too blurry? Or too large, so that when you see the image scaled down, you won't see the difference?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! What are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: Sorry. Can’t remember. Just used one I had, 400x400 or so.

Comment: You were right! The resolution on the image I was using was too large to notice the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As @haraldK mentioned, my image was too large to notice a difference. The code works as expected.